# Difference between Object.create(null) vs {}?

Tags: javascript, object

Is there a difference between objects created via the `Object.create(null)` syntax, vs the `{}` syntax?

From the node v5.6.0 REPL:

```
> var a = Object.create(null)
undefined
> var b = {}
undefined
> a == b
false
> a.prototype
undefined
> b.prototype
undefined
```

Comment: Only functions have a `prototype` property by default. That has nothing to do with the actual (internal) prototype of an object. What you want to use is `Object.getPrototypeOf(a)` and `Object.getPrototypeOf(b)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Objects made from `Object.create(null)` are totally empty -- they do not inherit anything from Object.prototype.

Empty objects do.

In the following example, I'm checking for the property of `toString`

```js
var fromNull = Object.create(null);
console.log(typeof fromNull.toString);
var emptyObject = {};
console.log(typeof emptyObject.toString);
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference.

With `{}` you create an object who's prototype is `Object.prototype`. But doing `Object.create(null)` creates an object who's prototype is `null`.

On the surface, they appear to be the same but in the latter case, you don't inherit basic functions attached to the Object prototype.

```js
var objPrototype = {};
console.log(objPrototype.toString());
var nullPrototype = Object.create(null);
console.log(nullPrototype.toString());
```